# Polymer: Nesting content inside of content

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, shadow-dom, content-tag

```
<!-- my-poly -->
<template>
  <content select=".useBtn">
    <button id="defaultBtn">
      <content select=".useBtnIcon">
        Button
      </content>
    </button>
  </content>
</template>
```

So if my Element gets used, the User can input a Button which will be shown instead of the `defaultBtn`. But if no Button is given, the `defaultBtn` with the Button Text will be shown. But  the user also should have the Option to use the `defaultBtn` and to input a text or icon which will be shown in the Button.

If I use a `<div class="useBtn"></div>` it will be used as the Button. But `<div class="useBtnIcon"> BtnText</div>` does not seem to work. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec its not going to work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#content-insertion-points

> The content element that satisfies all of the following conditions represents a content insertion point:
>
> - The root node of the content element is a shadow root
> - **There is no other content element in the ancestors of the content element**
> - There is no shadow element in the ancestors of the content element

With this in mind, i guess, you cant make this thing work with nestetd content elements.

This one will work. Custom Icon wins if both are applied

```
<polymer-element name="the-button">
    <template>

        <content id="contentButton" select=".useBtn">
            <button id="PREFIXEDdefaultBtn">
                Default Button
            </button>
        </content>

        <button id="defaultBtnWithCustomIcon">
            <!--be sure that this content element doesnt contain a default set -->
            <content id="contentIcon" select=".useBtnIcon"></content>
        </button>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('the-button', {
            domReady: function () {
                var customIcon = this.$.contentIcon;

                var disNodes = customIcon.getDistributedNodes();
                //Test if the content element contains distributed nodes.
                if (disNodes.length !== 0) {
                    this.$.contentButton.remove();
                } else {
                    // the button is customized, remove the icon
                    this.$.defaultBtnWithCustomIcon.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I knew i could get it to work with Dart or JS, but hoped it maybe would be possible without it...  
But the Spec did answer my Question

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your inner `<content>` element is purged when the outer `<content>` element selects its content.

Comment: But it does work if I put stuff into the content. And if i leave the polymer-element empty the default content will be shown. And if i put something into my polymer-element, it will be shown instead of the default input.

Comment: i actually use this quite often to give my element a default content

Comment: I can be wrong, but have never seen this and think to remember that this didn't do anything useful when I tried. Interesting that you had different experience. What happens when the element actually has children? Is your default content then replaced? This would probably remove the inner `<content>` tag too.

Comment: Which element do you mean?   If i put an element with children into my Polymer Element, everything gets displayed, but not the default content.

Comment: I assume if you have something like `<my-poly>xxx</my-poly>` then ` <button id="defaultBtn">...</button>` is replaced by `xxx` and then there is no `<content select=".useBtnIcon">` anymore to select the other content.

Comment: Well the first content does only select elements with the class `useBtn`. So the Button containing the second content should still be there if i dont use an Element with `useBtn`

Comment: Not when the first `<content>` element replaces its content with `xxx`. By removing the `#defaultButton` the inner `<content>` element would be removed as well.

Comment: since the second content is inside of the Button, it shouldnt get removed only its content ("Button") should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a jsfiddle or plnkr or anything for this? Polymer imports so many things, it's hard to trouble-shoot an issue without building our own project ourselves.

Without having the source to trouble-shoot this, it sounds like you might need to add the attributes to allow users to change preferences within your element in the `<polymer-element>` tag:

`<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="defaultBtn inputBtn">`

See here: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping

That should allow users to configure your custom element. Once again, without having the code to tinker with, not sure if this is going to work for your situation?